# Error installing rails - permission denied when running 'gem install rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I am new to programming and trying to install Rails on Mac Yosemite v10.10, but  I get the following error when running `$ gem install rails`.  How do I avoid this error and install rails?

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/usename/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.1.7/README.md`

I'm using ruby version 2.0.0p481.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make this:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER": ~/.rbenv
```

This function for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your rbenv installation was incorrectly installed as it had elevated privileges which caused your user account to not have write access to ~/.rbenv.

Do `sudo chown -R pgrennin ~/.rbenv`. This will take ownership of the directory

Answer (score 1):

You probably accidentally installed `rails` with `sudo` before. This installed Rails files owned by `root` and not you, so now you can't update them. To fix this you'll have to repossess those files with `chown`:

`sudo chown -R "$USER" ~/.rbenv`

(`"$USER"` is a variable that contains your username)

Answer (score 0):

If using rbenv

rbenv local 2.0.0-p247 before gem install bundler

more reference : https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#readme